# When go to back, how to get previous input value

Tags: javascript, html

It's my html body code.

```html
    <body>
    
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" oninput="change()">
    <input type="text" id="test" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" onclick="print()" value="submit">
    <a href="http://naver.com">naver</a>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('ready finished');
        });

        window.onload = function() {
            console.log('load finsihed');
            console.log('#search:::', document.getElementById("search").value);
            print();
        };
        function change() {
            $("#test").val($('#search').val())
            console.log('change:::::::::', $('#search').val())
        }

        function print() {
            console.log('test::::', $('#search').val());
        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

When I go back from naver link page to my html page, the #search input tag's value is kept.
But console.log says that is empty.
So I try to debug, and it's empty while `window.onload` event proceed
I want to get my #search input value when users go back.

my console
[image: my console]

---

## Solution

I found the solution thanks to comment of `lastr2d2`!
Use `setTimeout` in `onload` function as follows.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('load finsihed');
  console.log('#search:::', document.getElementById("search").value);
  // print();
  setTimeout(print, 0);
};
```

It works very well. I think the operation of changing the `input` or `select` tag's value is in the rendering queue, and the operation of the `onload` function seems to be executed first because it is in the stack without `setTimeout` function. But, when using `setTimeout` function for the `print` function in `onload` function, then it goes to the callback queue, and because the rendering queue is prior to callback queue, `input` value seems to be printed very well.

Comment: Use local storage to preserve the value.

Comment: Have you tried putting `print()` into the `$(document).ready(` function?

Comment: after a few tries, I found that `setTimeout(print, 0);` is the only way I can find to get the value. There must be something that happened after the `DOMContentLoaded` event

Comment: I tried putting print() in ready function, but ready is called earilear than load...

Comment: local storage... It may be good.. but I need to get values of many input tags!!

Comment: setTimeout(print, 0); .. I think It is the best in my situation!!! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onkeydown='' and perform a function each time you enter a search value
and then update the href attribute for the anchor tag in that function

```
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" oninput="change()">
<input type="text" id="test" style="display: none;">
<input type="button" onclick="print()" value="submit">
<a href="http://naver.com">naver</a>

<script>
   function change() {
      var text = $('#search').val();
      var new_search_val = 'http://naver.com?search_val='+text;
      $('#search_link_upd').attr('href', new_search_val);
   }
</script>
```

you can then get the search value in the next page with this method in this page :
https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/